# Element inside overflow auto container dosent have correct width (of all combined childs)

Tags: html, css, sass, overflow

I have a wrapper `<div>` with a fixed width and an inner `<div>`, which contains a list of several items that are together wider than the parent `<div>`.

As soon as the content get's wider than the wrapper `<div>`, I want a vertical scrollbar.

This works very well, but unfortunately, the inner `<div>` just has the same width as my wrapper div. the list items overflow the inner `<div>`, but when I set a background color for the inner `<div>`, it's only visible for this width of the wrapper `<div>`.

I want the inner `<div>` to have the same width as its child elements.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Here is an example code:

```css
.slider-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  background: grey;
  overflow: auto;
}

.slider-pane {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
  
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <div class="slider-pane">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Link to easy editable jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/gcx9zws2/

As you can see in the example, the red and yellow background ends on the width of the wrapper element. But I need it the same width as all list items together.
I don't know how many elements will be in the list later, so a pure CSS solution is preferred.

Thank you for any help.

Cheers
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `width:100%` from the `ul` (replace with a `min-width` if you want the element to be at least 100% wide if there’s less items), and make it `inline-flex` instead of `flex`.

And for the `div.slider-pane`, set `display: inline-block`, if you want the yellow to grow as well. (And again, add a min-width if necessary.)

```css
.slider-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  background: grey;
  overflow: auto;
}

.slider-pane {
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
  
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <div class="slider-pane">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man! Works like a charm :) can you explain why it has to be inline-block and inline-flex?

Comment: Normal blocks extend only to the width of their parent, and then you got overflow happening _inside_ them, inline-block/inline-flex behave differently, they allow the element to grow as far as the content requires, without that causing overflow inside.

Comment: @nonnnnn inline displays across, block displays down - inline-block is a combination of the two so you get the background across + down (and it will adjust on smaller devices depending on width) [in layman's terms]

Comment: @nonnnnn note that inline-flex is not needed here. The upper inline-block is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest adding `overflow: auto` to the **inner div** (`.slider-pane`) instead of `.slider-wrapper`. This would keep the **outer div** staying the right size, but the **inner div** would then **overflow** with a slider correctly.

See this pen if you like: https://codepen.io/JackofD/pen/LoGNjP